# Discrete Mathematics - Composition of Relations

Tags: relations

Can anyone help me, please, solve these problems below?

**1.** Find the relations $R, S$ on the same set $X$, so that
$R∘S \neq S∘R.$

**2.** Find the relation $R$ on the suitable set $X$, so that
$\forall n \in \mathbb N: R^n \neq R^{n+1}$.
The expression $R^n$ means n-times composed relation $R$,
i.e. $R^n = R∘R∘...∘R$ (n-times).

Edit:
I am not really sure what should be the output of these problems. If I should write a general formula of the reations or I can just name one example.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: For the first question let $X=\{0,1\}$, and try to find relations $R$ and $S$ on $X$ such that $R\circ S=\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ and $S\circ R=\{\langle 1,1\rangle\}$.

For the second, find a set and a relation on that set whose associated digraph looks like this:

$$\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet\longrightarrow\bullet\longrightarrow\ldots$$